# How to include one html page(as header) in another html page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I am trying to include an html page that will be header to my main page. Both pages are deployed to different servers. I currently doing it using frames. The header currently has some fixed width and I am not able to change its width I need it to fit the screen of my main page. 
Is it possible using frames or is there any other approach I could use for this?

Comment: Use a master page in ASP.net if you are using asp.net. Looks like you are using asp.net?

Comment: I have edited my question to add more detail. Both pages are at different servers.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below: I am accessing the header content through a url like "www.testsiteheader.com/header.html".

Answer (score 1):

You could use php (in case your server is able to run php files) Assuming your html files are called "header.html" and "content.html", the php file could look like that:

```
<html>
<?php
$HEADER_URL = "www.testsiteheader.com/header.html";
Include($HEADER_URL);
Include("content.html");
?>
</html>
```

As an example, this code:

```
<?php
Include("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047619/how-to-include-one-html-pageas-header-in-another-html-page");
?>
```

made the site look like this:
http://imgur.com/QB5MZu6

**IMPORTANT:**
You might have to change this in your php-config file:

```
allow_url_include = Off
```

TO

```
allow_url_include = On
```

Comment: eidted my initial answer to better suit the question

Comment: While your answer might be technically correct, the author does not use PHP, or has monetioned it (in the tags section).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out^^ I´ve had a simple answer in mind, which solves the general problem, so I didnt bother that much about the tags. Sorry about that. Because the author wrote "any other approach" I´ve assumed that he might be interested in all anwsers, even answers, which use things he didnt mention (maybe because he didnt think about them ;))

Comment: the php won't work for me actually since server is not able to run php files

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and Ajax to manage this :

The following function will run on the `document.ready` event and call the Ajax function of jQuery to access the `URL` set in an `asynchronous` manner, if the code errors the `error` function is executed and an error will be displayed on the page. If successful the `success` function will execute and set the `DivName` controls' html content to the retrieved object.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'MyPage.aspx', //path to external file
            async: true,
            error:function(ajaxrequest){
                $('#DivName').html('Error fetching content. Server Response: '+ajaxrequest.responseText);
            },
            success:function(content){
                $('#DivName').html(content);
            }
        });
    });
```

This code relies on the fact you have an external page called `MyPage.aspx` and a control on the current page with ID of `DivName`

Comment: I am accessing the header content through a url like "www.testsiteheader.com/header.html". Will the solution work in this case?

Comment: Ah, re-read your edited question. Unfortunately this probably won't work for cross domain calls. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) for details, although this talks about Services it should have some relevance.